# Is the encryption schema of public key algorithms generally known?

Tags: pgp, asymmetric

I understand the difference between public and private keys, but how exactly is data encrypted using the keys? And is the encryption schema of for example PGP known? Is it open source or at least known what it does step by step?

Comment: In a word: yes. This is a particularly vague question though, and as such probably can't result in a great answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [applied cryptography](https://mrajacse.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/applied-cryptography-2nd-ed-b-schneier.pdf):

> If I take a letter, lock it in a safe, hide the safe somewhere in New York, then
>   tell you to read the letter, that’s not security. That’s obscurity. On the other
>   hand, if I take a letter and lock it in a safe, and then give you the safe along
>   with the design specifications of the safe and a hundred identical safes with
>   their combinations so that you and the world’s best safecrackers can study the
>   locking mechanism—and you still can’t open the safe and read the
>   letter—that’s security.

PGP generally uses RSA to encrypt *keys* although others can be used.

RSA is comically simple:

encrypt: c = m^e mod(n).

decrypt: m = c^d mod(n).

where c = ciphertext, m = message , nd=private key, ne = public key

Then the message is further encrypted with a symmetric cipher. While this is generally [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), OpenPGP uses [CAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST-128)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the cryptographic algorithms in common use, including RSA, AES, SHA-256, DES, etc., and the common protocols that use them, including TLS/SSL, PGP, etc., are all publicly documented, and well-studied.

This follows [Kerckhoffs's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle) that states that "A cryptosystem should be secure even if everything about the system, except the key, is public knowledge."

In other words, if people didn't understand how PGP worked at the deepest levels, they would have no reason to trust it (and many reasons to suspect it may have contained a diabolical flaw.)  But because it was published in the open, where everyone who wanted to was able to analyze the design, the protocols, and the code itself, that gave people the ability to read the code for themselves, and decide for themselves whether or not it was trustworthy.

As a matter of fact, PGP was developed during an era where the USA was restricting international trade in arms.  The US classifies cryptography as a dual use technology, meaning it could be useful to civilians, but it could also be used for military purposes.  These laws were used to restrict the export of PGP.  However, freedom of the press is a right; so Phillip Zimmerman, the author of PGP [published a book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262240394) containing the printed source code, as a book is legal to export to anywhere.  People outside of the US were free to type it in to their computers, and have strong encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The most common asymmetric encryption algorithm is RSA. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) about it does a great job of explaining how it works. Some competence in mathematics is required, though.

Answer (score 0):

> And is the encryption schema of for example PGP known? Is it open source or at least known what it does step by step?

Yes on all counts.  There have been multiple versions of the specification over the years; the most recent one is [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), but [there are other related documents as well](http://openpgp.org/about/standard/).  [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/) is a very popular open-source implementation.